# How to convert this file-reading function into a class

Tags: python, class, authentication, python-class

I have this code:

```
username = str(input("Enter Username: "))
password = str(input("Enter Password: "))
def search_username(file_path, username, password):
    usernameTruthValue = False
    passwordTruthValue = False
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        # read all content of a file
        content = file.read()
        # check if string present in a file
        if username in content:
            usernameTruthValue = True
            print("Username Valid")
        else:
            print("ERROR")
        if password in content:
            passwordTruthValue = True
            print("Password Valid")
        else:
            print("ERROR")
        if usernameTruthValue and passwordTruthValue == True:
            print("Welcome")


search_username(r'/Users/name/PyCharmProjects/ADSProject/username.txt', username, password)
```

It's supposed to check strings in a text file and verify whether they are there or not. It is supposed to be a very simplified version of a username/login system. I am really struggling with turning this into a class. How am I supposed to go about this?

Thank you

```
class Login():
    def __init__(self, file_path, username, password):
        self.file_path = file_path
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

def search_user_and_pass():
    usernametruthvalue = False
    passwordtruthvalue = False
    with open(self.file_path, 'r') as file:
            # read all content of a file
        content = file.read()
            # check if string present in a file
        if self.username in content:
                usernametruthvalue = True
        else:
                print("This username doesn't exist.")
        if self.password in content:
                passwordtruthvalue = True
        else:
                print("ERROR")
        if usernametruthvalue == True and passwordtruthvalue == True:
            print("yes")
            #call next function here
Login('/Users/name/pythonProjects/ADS/user_pass.txt', "Molly", "1234")
```

I am expecting to recieve a print error when I put in a wrong item, but I receive nothing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

At the very core, you should probably read up on what a Class method looks like, specifically the inferred self reference:

```
class Login():
    def __init__(self, file_path, username, password):
        self.file_path = file_path
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    def search_user_and_pass(self):
        ....
```

Otherwise, the class functions will not have any concept of `self`. Also verify all spacing is correct, as the code you have copied is not spaced correctly (same indent for class functions **init** and search_user_and_pass.

You also are not calling any method, the Login will return a Class instance, but since search_user_and_pass is not called in **init** that function is never invoked.

```
my_login = Login('/Users/name/pythonProjects/ADS/user_pass.txt', "Molly", "1234")
my_login.seach_user_and_pass()
```